# Meaning of sparse=False pre-processing data with OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I came across the meaning of setting `sparse=False` pre-processing my data with a OneHotEncoder. I did:

```py
ct = ColumnTransformer([
    ("scaling", StandardScaler(), sca_col), #sca_col containing 3 columns
    ("onehot", OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore'), ohe_col)]) #ohe_col containing 15 columns
```

Then I train my model with:

```py
feat = df.drop("label", axis=1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(feat, df.label, random_state=0)
ct.fit(X_train)
```

I get the error

```
[...]
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 151. GiB for an array with shape (239076, 84497) and data type float64
```

with the right shape according to my data and columns, but obviously not fitting in my RAM.

If I set `sparse=True`, which is default, it works.

In which case you need to set `sparse=False`, which I did for no obvious reasons a couple of weeks ago?

Comment: Note: since version 1.2: `sparse` was deprecated with 1.2 and will be removed with 1.4. Use `sparse_output` instead. [sklean.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting this flag, you choose to represent your data in a [sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) formatting. This saves a lot of memory when you have an array where most of the elements are zero.

From Scikit-learn's ColumTransformer documentation:

> sparse_thresholdfloat, default=0.3
>
> If the output of the different
> transformers contains sparse matrices, these will be stacked as a
> sparse matrix if the overall density is lower than this value. Use
> sparse_threshold=0 to always return dense. When the transformed output
> consists of all dense data, the stacked result will be dense, and this
> keyword will be ignored.

Whether to use a sparse matrix or not depends on the matrix's sparsity, which is the percentage of the values that are zero. In your case, if using a sparse matrix tackles your memory restrictions, then it's the way to go. In case your matrix is not sparse enough, you won't have any benefit in memory savings or any improvement in computational speed, if algorithms designed for sparse matrices are used.

Comment: Thanks, I get that. In what scenario would you need sparse=False? I can't figure it out...

Comment: If your matrix is not sparse enough, you won't have any benefit in memory savings or any improvement in computational speed, if algorithms designed for sparse matrices are used. I included this in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> In which case you need to set `sparse=False` ...?

Some algorithms are not written to operate on sparse matrices, and so forcing your `OneHotEncoder` to produce dense output is desirable despite the additional memory use.  (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66456410/10495893) for a recent example.)  It's also easier to view the output of a dense matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If your matrix is say < 64KB columns/rows then a *very* fast *BLAS* routine can be used that uses a mix of super-highly-optimized low-level *c* and/or *fortran* matrix primitives.  It takes a reasonably high degree of sparsity to "catch up" to the speed of using those libraries on dense matrix calculations.